# How to get these images alt tag url with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bunch of HTML code which contain these images:

```
<img alt=\"http://www.adsf1.net/static/1231.jpg\" width=\"100%\">
<img alt=\"http://www.1322.com/files/150818g58.jpg\" width=\"100%\">
<img alt=\"http://www.aerwef.org/sda/sdfawe.jpg\" width=\"100%\">
```

I manage to match these images with this regex

```
<img[^>]+\s*\/?>
```

But, I would like to get the url from the alt tag using JS, and store it into an array.

I would like to get a JS array like this (based on the above example)

```
["http://www.adsf1.net/static/1231.jpg", "http://www.1322.com/files/150818g58.jpg", "http://www.aerwef.org/sda/sdfawe.jpg"]
```

Comment: That isn't HTML what you have there. Why are you trying to use regex instead of DOM methods?

Comment: why alt instead of src?

Comment: regex is not the right tool for parsing HTML.

Comment: @PeeHaa Isn't that regex the fastest way to match a certain pattern? Using DOM methods seems to be a bit troublesome.

Comment: @VasiliyVanchuk that's the problem, the website I want to parse use alt instead of src.

Comment: @adeneo Sorry for asking it. Which is the right tool for parsing HTML? DOM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @pawan bhardwaj for the tips and clue. I have modified his code for a better match.

```
<img.*?alt=\\"(http[^"]*)\\".*?>
```

For others who are looking for something similar, hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex :

```
<img alt=\\"(http[^"]*)\\".*
```

Hope this helps.

link : *https://regex101.com/r/mI3hV1/1*

Comment: Thank you for your help! This regex made my day. I have modified a little base on yours to better match my questions. Anw, thanks a lot!